# code_prettify not working for Julia in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, julia

I am using Julia 1.8.4 in Jupyter, however, I get the following error message when I start it up.

```
[code_prettify] Sorry, can't use kernel language julia. 

Configurations are currently only defined for the following languages: python, r, javascript
See readme for more details.
```

If I click "Ok", I am able to run the code in the cells but Jupyter does not highlight Julia code. It continues highlighting Python code and syntax. Is there a way I can fix this?

Or could someone refer me to the documentation?

Comment: Don't think I've come across this before. The docs for IJulia are here: https://julialang.github.io/IJulia.jl/stable/ - how did you install IJulia?

Comment: I installed Julia using the method mentioned here  - https://datatofish.com/add-julia-to-jupyter/

Comment: That's different from the regular install instructions: can you just start a fresh Julia REPL and do `using IJulia; notebook()` and then start a notebook from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the error message indicates, `code_prettify` only has configurations inbuilt for Python, Javascript, and R. [From the docs](https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nbextensions/code_prettify/README_code_prettify.html):

> Example implementations are provided for prettifiers for ipython, ir and ijavascript kernels which should work out of the box ...
> Other languages may be added as defaults in the future

Support for Julia is yet to be added, hence the error message.

That said, `code_prettify` is only needed if you want to reformat your code (semi-)automatically. Syntax highlighting should work regardless, without any extension, and based on my testing, it does. Loading a notebook with a Julia kernel, the error message appears in the console, but the code is syntax-highlighted as usual.

So, if the syntax highlighting problem persists across notebook restarts, the issue must be with some other part of your notebook setup.